# How to select an input OR a select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

how can one select an input "or" a select element with jQuery? I have a form, and I want to get the first element of that form that is an input or a select. So, this $('#myForm').find('input:first') or $('#myForm').find('select:first'). Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#myForm').find('input:first, select:first').first()
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$('#myForm select, #myForm input').first()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
$('#myForm :input').first()
```

`:input` "Matches all input, textarea, select and button elements." from the [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/input).
`.first()` "Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set." also from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/first/).